# Bind <svelte:window> to `onbeforeunload`

Tags: svelte, svelte-3

I was hoping to bind to `<svelte:window>` but have no luck.

```html
<!-- doesn't work -->
<svelte:window on:beforeunload={() => true} />

<!-- doesn't work -->
<svelte:window on:onbeforeunload={() => true} />

<!-- doesn't work -->
<svelte:window on:beforeUnload={() => true} />
```

in all instances, `window.onbeforeunload` is `null`

I ended up just going with `window.onbeforeunload = () => true` but was wondering why setting on the element didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to set the event `returnValue` when using [`svelte:window`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-window)

```
<script>

  function beforeUnload() {
    // Cancel the event as stated by the standard.
    event.preventDefault();
    // Chrome requires returnValue to be set.
    event.returnValue = '';
    // more compatibility
    return '...';
  }

</script>

<svelte:window on:beforeunload={beforeUnload}/>
```

The reason for this is that writing `on:event={handler}` in svelte, is equivalent to writing `node.addEventListener(event, handler, options)`

It turns out that when attaching `beforeunload` using `addEventListener`, then [you need to set the event `returnValue` and/or return a value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

> However note that not all browsers support this method, and some
> instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy
> methods:
>
> - assigning a string to the event's returnValue property
> - returning a string from the event handler.

Registering the event using `window.onbeforeunload` only requires a return value

Comment: In my case I just needed a `on:beforeunload|preventDefault`.