# Svelte How to trap browser back button or unload?

Tags: svelte, onbeforeunload, svelte-component

I would like to fully control navigation in my Svelte SPA App.

Is there a way to trap the back, forward, and refresh buttons so that I can give a warning about loosing the page?

Comment: There is but it's not very customizable, I think all major browsers disabled the ability to give a custom message but they all say something like "Are you sure? You have unsaved changes". What you need is beforeunload, you can run it from within a svelte:window tag as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62567071/bind-sveltewindow-to-onbeforeunload)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Detect Browser Back Button event - Cross Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser)

Comment: Are you using Sapper? or `svelte-routing`? Which routing library are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're not using Sapper or a third-party Svelte routing library, you can achieve that using `beforeunload` as proposed in the comments. Here's a snippet with TypeScript.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    export let name: string;

    function beforeunload(event: BeforeUnloadEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return event.returnValue = '';
    }
</script>

<p>{name}</p>

<svelte:window on:beforeunload={beforeunload}/>
```

`on:beforeunload` might throw a type error but it should work fine.