# how to show a loader in svelte when page is loading

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

We have the following method available to know whether pages are loading in sveltekit:

```
import { navigating } from '$app/stores'
```

What is its equivalent in svelte (i.e without sveltekit)?

OR

How to achieve this functionality in frontend.

Comment: when you say "equivalent in svelte" are you saying "without sveltekit"? Are you using another 3rd party router or are you just saying how to make a loading animation on the initial page load of the app

Comment: @Zachiah without sveltekit!

Comment: > Are you using another 3rd party router or are you just saying how to make a loading animation on the initial page load of the app

Answer (score 3):

There is no "equivalent in Svelte" because Svelte itself is just for components and has no routing.

Implementing such a router correctly is *really* complex, you would need to:

- Intercept all clicks on links and prevent the default navigation
- Dynamically load code and data for the new page
- Cleanly replace the current page with the new one
- Update the URL to reflect the new location via the history API
- Listen to history API events to be able to go back/forward accordingly, replacing the page again
- Save scroll location on every navigation and restoring it once the page is fully replaced
- Implement stores that provide client router state such as `navigating`
- Implement functions to do such navigation programmatically

Possibly there is even more. So don't reinvent the wheel; either use SvelteKit or some other routing library.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `beforeunload` event to find out whenever we've started navigating. There is an example with with Svelte in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62569233/6882617).

We can also create our own `navigating` store by listening to the event within a Svelte `readable` store.

You can copy this block of code:

```js
import { readable } from 'svelte/store';

export const navigating = readable(false, (set) => {
    // Make sure that window exists
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return;

    const navigatingStarted = () => {
        // Notify subscribers that we are now navigating
        set(true);

        // If page hasn't 'unload' event hasn't fired in 500ms, it's probably cancelled
        let unloaded = false;
        const confirmUnloaded = () => (unloaded = true);
        window.addEventListener('unload', confirmUnloaded);
        window.setTimeout(() => {
            if (!unloaded) {
                set(false);
                window.removeEventListener('unload', confirmUnloaded);
            }
        }, 500);
    };

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', navigatingStarted);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', navigatingStarted);
});
```

And then use it like this:

```html
<script>
  import { navigating } from './navigate-store'
</script>

<p>Demo:</p>
<p>
    {#if $navigating}
        Navigating!
    {:else}
        Not navigating!
    {/if}
</p>
```

[You can see a working example in this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sveltejs-kit-template-default-3lngiv?file=src%2Froutes%2F%2Blayout.svelte) (technically, this demo is running in a SvelteKit app, but the `<a/>` hyperlinks have `rel="external"` so they are not actually using the SvelteKit router)

Comment: I see that it is working in the stackblitz link but not working for me as expected. I was lazily loaded pages. But I found a working example here: https://svelte.dev/repl/09abb8c287f745169f66f62d51f766d5?version=4.1.2

Comment: Nice work! I didn't realise you already had client-side routing (eg. svelte-navigator). My answer only works when the page completely unloads - like using Svelte with a multi-page framework like Django / Astro / .NET MVC etc.